# How to JOIN a table with itself and display it as a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table named PRODUCT_PRICE:

```
CREATE TABLE [TEST].[PRODUCT_PRICE]
(
    [PRICE_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PRODUCT_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PRICE_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [IS_SALE_PRICE] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [UNIT_PRICE] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL
)
```

It has the following records:

```
PRICE_ID PRODUCT_ID PRICE_DATE  IS_SALE_PRICE UNIT_PRICE
-------- ---------- ----------  ------------- ----------
1        15         2015-05-12  False         0,05
2        15         2015-05-12  True          0,04
3        25         2015-05-12  False         1,45
4        35         2015-05-12  True          2,65
```

Edit: There can only be two prices - a purchase price and a sale price. There can't be 3 or more rows with same `PRODUCT_ID` and `PRICE_DATE`.

I want to write a `SELECT` statement that results in the following:

```
PRICE_ID PRODUCT_ID PRICE_DATE  IS_SALE_PRICE UNIT_PRICE PRICE_ID_2 IS_SALE_PRICE_2 UNIT_PRICE_2
-------- ---------- ----------  ------------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ------------
1        15         2015-05-12  False         0,05       2          True            0,04
3        25         2015-05-12  False         1,45       NULL       NULL            NULL
4        35         2015-05-12  True          2,65       NULL       NULL            NULL
```

I tried `FULL OUTER JOIN` but it results in 4 rows rather than 3 which is correct but not what I am looking for:

```
SELECT
    PR1.*,
    PR2.PRICE_ID AS PRICE_ID_2,
    PR2.IS_SALE_PRICE AS IS_SALE_PRICE_2,
    PR2.UNIT_PRICE AS UNIT_PRICE_2
FROM PRODUCT_PRICE AS PR1
FULL OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_PRICE AS PR2
    ON PR1.PRODUCT_ID = PR2.PRODUCT_ID
    AND PR1.PRICE_DATE = PR2.PRICE_DATE
    AND PR1.PRICE_ID <> PR2.PRICE_ID
    AND PR1.IS_SALE_PRICE <> PR2.IS_SALE_PRICE
WHERE
    PR1.PRICE_DATE = '20150512'
ORDER BY PR1.PRICE_ID
```

Result of the above query:

```
| PRICE_ID | PRODUCT_ID | PRICE_DATE | IS_SALE_PRICE | UNIT_PRICE | PRICE_ID_2 | IS_SALE_PRICE_2 | UNIT_PRICE_2 |
|----------|------------|------------|---------------|------------|------------|-----------------|--------------|
|        1 |         15 | 2015-05-12 |         false |       0.05 |          2 |            true |         0.04 |
|        2 |         15 | 2015-05-12 |          true |       0.04 |          1 |           false |         0.05 |
|        3 |         25 | 2015-05-12 |         false |       1.45 |     (null) |          (null) |       (null) |
|        4 |         35 | 2015-05-12 |          true |       2.65 |     (null) |          (null) |       (null) |
```

Basically I want to `JOIN` a table with itself and remove duplicates.

Note: `PRICE_ID` is an `identity` field (primary key). But natural key is the `PRODUCT_ID`, `PRICE_DATE` pair. I want a row for each unique `PRODUCT_ID` and `PRICE_DATE`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d84d/3/0)

Comment: You want one row for each PRODUCT_ID? What result do you expect if there are 3 (or 4) PRICE_ID's with same PRODUCT_ID?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Done, added to the end. Why so aggressive with closing? 2 close votes already. I tried to explain as plain as possible.

Comment: Do you really need the `PRICE_ID`? I'm thinking this can be done with a dynamic crosstab.

Comment: @jarlh Added "Note" part.

Comment: @wewesthemenace, yes, I need PRICE_ID. Any answers are welcome.

Comment: So, again, if there are 3 or more rows with same PRODUCT_ID and PRICE_DATE, which result do you expect?

Comment: @AnarKhalilov: Even if it's closed it can be reopened. But it's always better to provide all relevant informations from the beginning. Btw, don't post images because: 1. it's additional traffic, some are on mobiles 2. images will die in future 3. we cannot copy-paste it. Instead post the sql as plain text but nicely formatted.

Comment: @jarlh Oh, I see what you're trying to ask, good point. There can only be two prices - a purchase price and a sale price. Having 3 or more rows is not a possibility.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I believe if stackoverflow.com has an "add image" button, then why should we not use this feature? A 17KB file is not too much even for a mobile user. What do you mean "images will die"? They are hosted on SO after all...

Comment: @AnarKhalilov: even if only  the last argument remains, you don't really save time by creating a screenshot and posting it instead of copy-pasting the query from SSMS, but we save time if we can use your query as template and understand better what you're trying to achieve. Images may be useful if you have CSS or layout questions for example.

Comment: @AnarKhalilov, you can do this without using `JOIN`. See my answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, get your point but I wasn't being lazy as you can see from SELECT results code blocks. I didn't copy and paste them but write them. The reason I posted a screenshot was that I thought people will come up with a different solution than mine and the script will be unnecessary. I won't assume it next time though.

Going from "don't post images because 1,2,3" to "images may be useful for CSS"... To be totally honest with you, I didn't like your bullying attitude. This is probably the only thing I don't like here in SO. People with high rep treating lower rep people like noobs.

Comment: @AnarKhalilov, I've edited your question and replace the image with an sql fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure that there will only be a maximum of 2 rows for each `PRODUCT_ID` - `PRICE_DATE` combination, you can use conditional aggregation instead of `JOIN`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d84d/1/0)

```
SELECT
      PRICE_ID       = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN PRICE_ID END),
      PRODUCT_ID,
      PRICE_DATE,
      IS_SALE_PRICE  = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN CAST(IS_SALE_PRICE AS INT) END),
      UNIT_PRICE     = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN UNIT_PRICE END),
      PRICE_ID2      = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN PRICE_ID END),
      IS_SALE_PRICE2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN CAST(IS_SALE_PRICE AS INT) END),
      UNIT_PRICE2    = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN UNIT_PRICE END)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID, PRICE_DATE ORDER BY IS_SALE_PRICE)
    FROM PRODUCT_PRICE
)t
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID, PRICE_DATE
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID, PRICE_DATE
```

**Result**

```
| PRICE_ID | PRODUCT_ID | PRICE_DATE | IS_SALE_PRICE | UNIT_PRICE | PRICE_ID2 | IS_SALE_PRICE2 | UNIT_PRICE2 |
|----------|------------|------------|---------------|------------|-----------|----------------|-------------|
|        1 |         15 | 2015-05-12 |             0 |       0.05 |         2 |              1 |        0.04 |
|        3 |         25 | 2015-05-12 |             0 |       1.45 |    (null) |         (null) |      (null) |
|        4 |         35 | 2015-05-12 |             1 |       2.65 |    (null) |         (null) |      (null) |
```

---

If you insist on using `JOIN`, you can use `FULL JOIN`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d84d/2/0)

```
SELECT
    PRICE_ID         = CASE WHEN PP.PRICE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN PP.PRICE_ID ELSE SP.PRICE_ID END,
    PRODUCT_ID       = CASE WHEN PP.PRICE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN PP.PRODUCT_ID ELSE SP.PRODUCT_ID END,
    PRICE_DATE       = CASE WHEN PP.PRICE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN PP.PRICE_DATE ELSE SP.PRICE_DATE END,
    IS_SALE_PRICE    = CASE WHEN PP.PRICE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN PP.IS_SALE_PRICE ELSE SP.IS_SALE_PRICE END,
    UNIT_PRICE       = CASE WHEN PP.PRICE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN PP.UNIT_PRICE ELSE SP.UNIT_PRICE END,
    PRICE_ID2        = CASE WHEN PP.PRICE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN SP.PRICE_ID END,
    IS_SALE_PRICE2   = CASE WHEN PP.PRICE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN SP.IS_SALE_PRICE END,
    UNIT_PRICE2      = CASE WHEN PP.PRICE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN SP.UNIT_PRICE END
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM PRODUCT_PRICE
    WHERE IS_SALE_PRICE = 0
)AS PP
FULL JOIN(
    SELECT *
    FROM PRODUCT_PRICE
    WHERE IS_SALE_PRICE = 1
)AS SP
    ON PP.PRODUCT_ID = SP.PRODUCT_ID
    AND PP.PRICE_DATE = SP.PRICE_DATE
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID, PRICE_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it works. What about performance when the table has let say 10K rows? is it better than using a JOIN?

Comment: The first one, conditional aggregation is better, especially given the right index.

Comment: That's great. As my personal rule, I will wait a bit for more answers before marking it as the best answer. Thanks!
Also, I ran out of upvotes for today but don't worry, I will asap as you deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `PRICE_ID=1` vs `PRICE_ID =2` and `PRICE_ID=2` vs `PRICE_ID=1`
So you have a repeated row.

In the `ON CLAUSE`, you should force to only `join` when `PRICE_ID1 < PRICE_ID2`

Add this to the ON CLAUSE:

```
AND PR1.PRICE_ID < PR2.PRICE_ID
```

And use LEFT JOIN

With that changes u will get 4 rows, u need also to avoid the the row 2, because its already "inside" the row 1. So u only have to filter registers with that in the where clause:

```
AND PR1.PRICE_ID in (select min(PRICE_ID) from PRODUCT_PRICE group by PRODUCT_ID)
```

Comment: Just tried that. It doesn't JOIN, yes, but it doesn't prevent one of two rows (PRICE_ID=1 or 2) to NOT appear. Still 4 rows appear.

Comment: Its because u should use  JOIN        instead  of FULL OUTER JOIN.
Please try it. It will work

Comment: A regular inner JOIN will only return data when 2 rows per product/date. LEFT JOIN is needed for the cases when only 1 row for a product/date.

Comment: `AND PR2.PRICE_ID IS NOT NULL` has the same problem as the readon for not using inner join.

Comment: @Tirma, as jarlh stated, using JOIN will get rows 3&4 filtered out, just tried that. Using LEFT JOIN results in 4 rows.

Comment: @AnarKhalilov i understood the problem right now... sorry. give me a few minutes ;)

Comment: @Tirma, your last suggestion does not work when you have prices for let say next date: '2015-05-13'. I know what you need to correct but I'd rather  see you figure it out. ;)

Comment: Is changing the group by    and adding the date?
So you solved it. Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

Do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

```
select ...
from PRODUCT_PRICE p1
  FULL OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_PRICE p2
    ON  p1.PRODUCT_ID = p2.PRODUCT_ID
    AND p1.PRICE_DATE = p2.PRICE_DATE
    AND p1.IS_SALE_PRICE = 'true
    AND p2.IS_SALE_PRICE = 'false'
```

Write select list columns. And adjust IS_SALE_PRICE comparisons.

Alternative solution, derived tables `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
select ...
from (select * from PRODUCT_PRICE
      where  IS_SALE_PRICE = 'true') as p1
  FULL OUTER JOIN
     (select * from PRODUCT_PRICE
      where  IS_SALE_PRICE = 'false') as p2
    ON  p1.PRODUCT_ID = p2.PRODUCT_ID
    AND p1.PRICE_DATE = p2.PRICE_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just tried that to no avail. It returned only one row (joined rows with PRICE_ID=1 and 2). I think because when table p2 cannot be joined due to ON clause, p2.IS_SALE_PRICE='false' in WHERE clause fails. I mean this query selects ONLY if both sale and purchase prices exist.

Comment: Oops, classic error... Move WHERE conditions to ON when outer join... Have another try!

Comment: Still 4 rows. You need to add something to the WHERE clause to eliminate 1 row so result is 3 rows.